# The cost of PIT in Elasticsearch?

Tags: elasticsearch

I know that `scroll` has a lot of overhead in Elasticsearch, and that `search_after` is generally preferred. But what about PIT (Point in Time)? Does it also have the same overhead?

Is `search_after` still faster than PIT?

Comment: Since [PIT leverages `search_after`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/paginate-search-results.html#search-after), it doesn't really make sense to compare one vs the other.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since [PIT leverages `search_after`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/paginate-search-results.html#search-after), it doesn't really make sense to compare one vs the other. However, PIT was created as a more lightweight solution than scroll.

`search_after` alone doesn't give allow you an exact view of your data at a given moment in time. When you start paginating with `search_after`, if a `refresh` occurs while you're paginating, you might either re-read some data twice or miss some. The idea of PIT is to prevent that and allow you to paginate over a "point in time" snapshot of your data.

It is also worth noting that pagination is not the only use case for PIT. PIT allows to issue [several search and aggregation queries separately and still work on the same point-in-time data](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.10/release-highlights.html#points-in-time-for-search) in order to present consistent results.

So to answer your initial question, `search_after` alone will always carry less overhead than `search_after` used in conjunction with PIT (since PIT keeps a context). So it simply boils down to know whether it is important for you to query over a consistent context or if you don't really care.

Comment: If I share the same PIT between many searches, is it faster than performing those searches individually?

Comment: FWIW @MathiasLykkegaardLorenzen I did some testing of a sorted search_after search paging through a total of 6M hits and using `pit` does *not* improve performance, same with or without. Agree that's unexpected, you'd think it would save some work.

Comment: @Val "... However, PIT was created as a more lightweight solution than scroll. ..." Is there a link that explains how PIT is more lightweight than a scroll?

Comment: I found [this](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/issues/26472), but it doesn't talk about the cost aspect, it just mentions the forward-only restriction of scroll queries and the retry-page-skips caused by that.

Comment: @HakanSerce It makes no sense to talk about the absolute cost of PIT. However, what matters is that the cost of PIT is lower than the one of scroll.

Comment: @Val That is actually what I am trying to understand. What is it that makes PIT lower cost than scroll? Do you have any links that explain the design details of PIT compared to scroll?